# java excutable jar error

Tags: java, openjdk, minecraft

When I run the `java -jar` command it gives me this:

```
wolfgang@laptop1:~$ java -jar /home/wolfgang/Downloads/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2768-universal.jar
We appear to be missing one or more essential library files.
You will need to add them to your server before FML and Forge will run successfully.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:52)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:34)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try installing the Forge "Installer" `.jar` instead of the "Universal" `.jar`. You can download the Installer from Forge, make sure you're selecting the "Installer" option, not "Universal":

https://files.minecraftforge.net/

If that still doesn't help and you see the same error, you could try manually downloading the libraries required here:

https://www.extravm.com/billing/kb_downloads/fml_libs15.zip

Extract them to `/libraries` on your Minecraft server, then run the installation again:

`java -jar forge*installer.jar`